# Multiple Stored Procedure Outputs

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

Can't get this stored procedure to work. The procedure accept a tablename and other symbol input and sends multiple outputs. Not sure what I am I missing, but the dynamic query does not work. Help?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usrSetSymbolMetrics]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @TableName SYSNAME,
    @Symbol NVARCHAR(50),
    @LTDMean float output,
    @LTDStdev float output,
    @PYTDMean float output,
    @PYTDStdev float output,
    @YTDMean float output,
    @YTDStdev float output

AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    --Print @Symbol;
   DECLARE @SQLCommand NVARCHAR(MAX) = 
        N'SELECT @LTDMean=[LTD_MEAN], @LTDStdev=[LTD_STDEV], @PYTDMean=[PYTD_MEAN], @PYTDStdev=[PYTD_STDEV], @YTDMean=[YTD_MEAN], @YTDStdev=[YTD_STDEV] FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@TableName) + ' WHERE SYMBOL=@Symbol';

Print @SQLCommand;
    EXECUTE dbo.sp_executesql @sqlCommand
      , N'@Symbol NVARCHAR(50), @LTDMean FLOAT, @LTDStdev FLOAT, @PYTDMean FLOAT, @PYTDStdev FLOAT, @YTDMean FLOAT, @YTDStdev FLOAT'
      , @Symbol = @Symbol
      , @LTDMean = @LTDMean
      , @LTDStdev = @LTDStdev
      , @PYTDMean  = @PYTDMean
      , @PYTDStdev = @PYTDStdev
      , @YTDMean = @YTDMean
      , @YTDStdev = @YTDStdev;
END
```

Comment: What do you mean by not being able to get it to work? Do you get an error or unexpected result or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `OUTPUT` keyword:

```
EXECUTE dbo.sp_executesql @sqlCommand
  , N'@Symbol NVARCHAR(50), @LTDMean FLOAT OUTPUT, @LTDStdev FLOAT OUTPUT, @PYTDMean FLOAT OUTPUT, @PYTDStdev FLOAT OUTPUT, @YTDMean FLOAT OUTPUT, @YTDStdev FLOAT OUTPUT'
  , @Symbol = @Symbol
  , @LTDMean = @LTDMean OUTPUT 
  , @LTDStdev = @LTDStdev OUTPUT 
  , @PYTDMean  = @PYTDMean OUTPUT 
  , @PYTDStdev = @PYTDStdev OUTPUT 
  , @YTDMean = @YTDMean OUTPUT 
  , @YTDStdev = @YTDStdev OUTPUT ;
```